# How do I measure the size of a TextBlock in WPF before it is rendered?

Tags: wpf, textblock, measure

I have a WPF DataTemplate with two TextBlock controls (stacked) and then some other elements underneath.  Due to some complicated layout code, I need to know the height of the two TextBlock elements so that I can draw some fancy connector lines, and line up other controls, etc.

If I know the text that's going into the TextBlocks, and I know the font, etc., is there some way I can compute or measure the height of these TextBlocks without actually rendering them?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think it should be sufficient to call the [`UIElement.Measure(Size)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.measure.aspx) method and subsequently check the [`UIElement.DesiredSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.desiredsize.aspx) property. For more information, check the provided MSDN links.

Comment: +1, but note that in addition to the usual typeface and font size, there's also an (inherited) attached property that [affects font hinting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/08/24/wpf-4-0-text-stack-improvements.aspx) (whether to align to whole pixels or not), and this affects the width of the text. The attached property is `TextOptions.FormattingMode` -- make sure the value of this property on the object you're measuring matches the value on the object you're rendering (if they're not the same).

Comment: Just had the same issue and just calling `textblock.Measure(new Size());` aint enough. I had to use `textblock.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));` to get a result for `textblock.DesiredSize`

Comment: Remember, that `MinWidth` need to be set to 0, and `MaxWidth` set to PositiveInfinity before measuring, otherwise it will be capped by those values.

Comment: There must be something else, I'm getting DesiredSize.Height = 4.0. Not what I'm looking for and not what appears on screen.

Comment: I had also to set textBlock.Width and textBlock.Height to double.NaN, then measuring worked.

Answer (score 2):

The call to `UIElement.Measure(Size)`, takes as a parameter `Size`. The second call `UIElement.DesiredSize` returns whatever `Size` you passed into the `Measure` method.

I think this is the case because `UIElement` (`TextBlock` in this case) is NOT a child of any control (yet) and therefore `DesiredSize` has no reason to be anything different.

Comment: No, not necessarily. Even without adding the UIElement (in my case also a TextBlock) to a parent control, DesiredSize was set correctly after I called Measure with a sufficiently large availabe size as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate that this is a rather old question, but I have found that using the following code

```
        TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
        textBlock.Text = "NR valve";
        Size msrSize = new Size(100, 200);
        textBlock.Measure(msrSize);
        Size dsrdSize = textBlock.DesiredSize;
```

dsrdSize is returned as {47.05,15.96}.
The trick seems to be making the msrSize larger than the expected actual size. msrSize seems to act as a limit for the DesiredSize() result.
For example, using msrSize = new Size(10, 10), results in a dsrdSize of {10,10} here.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Size ShapeMeasure(TextBlock tb) {
    // Measured Size is bounded to be less than maxSize
    Size maxSize = new Size(
         double.PositiveInfinity, 
         double.PositiveInfinity);
    tb.Measure(maxSize);
    return tb.DesiredSize;
}

public static Testit() 
{
    TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
    textBlock.Text = "NR valve";

    Size text size = ShapeMeasure(textBlock);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And since Measure is defined in UIElement you can measure the shape of any UIElement derived object including TextBlock:

```
public static Size ShapeMeasure(UIElement e) {
// Measured Size is bounded to be less than maxSize
Size maxSize = new Size(
     double.PositiveInfinity, 
     double.PositiveInfinity);
e.Measure(maxSize);
return e.DesiredSize;
}
```