# How can I measure the size of a TextBlock before it is rendered

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to know the size of my Textblock before it is rendered.
I have gone through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988622/how-do-i-measure-the-size-of-a-textblock-in-wpf-before-it-is-rendered) but its not working (may be I am doing something wrong).
My Textblock is binded to the property in a ViewModel and in code behind I am monitoring the text changed event.

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyProperty, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" 
           TargetUpdated="OnTargetUpdated"/>
```

and code behind:

```
 private void OnTargetUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
    {    
        var tb = sender as TextBlock;
        var text =  tb .Text; // here I can see updated Text 
        var size = tb.DesiredSize; // here DesireSize value is 0
        tb.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity,
                                   Double.PositiveInfinity));
        tb.Arrange(new Rect(tb.DesiredSize));
        var width = tb.ActualWidth; // here actual width is coming 0
    }
```

Comment: you have to look at the ActualWidth and ActualHeight properties, DesiredSize is what the programmer specifies

Comment: ActualWidth is not working, see my edit above.

Comment: subscribe to the SizeChanged event and see if the size even changes, maybe you got a problem in your layout

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. I called UpdateLayout() method which updated ActualHeight and ActualWidth

```
var viewbox = new Viewbox { Child = contentPresenter };
        viewbox.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
        viewbox.Arrange(new Rect(viewbox.DesiredSize));
        viewbox.UpdateLayout();
        viewbox.Child = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: [how to calculate the textbock height and width in on load if i create textblock from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556019/how-to-calculate-the-textbock-height-and-width-in-on-load-if-i-create-textblock)

> Call Measure() then Arrange() and then ActualWidth and ActualHeight will be updated.

Comment: I have called Mesaure() and Arrange() (see my edited code above); but its still not working.